# How to bind a value to the "Gesture" property of the MouseBinding class? – WPF XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am currently trying to add the following line of code to my XAML file:

```
<MouseBinding Command="helix:ViewportCommands.Rotate" Gesture="{Binding ViewportRotateGesture}" />
```

The problem is that this doesn't work. Whenever I try to bind a string to the "Gesture" property, I get the following exception:

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Gesture' property of type 'MouseBinding'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.'

Using the "MouseAction" property instead of the "Gesture" property does work, however this doesn’t allow you to add any modifiers. Does anybody know how to bind a mouse gesture in combination with a modifier (for example Shift+LeftClick)?

Comment: It's covered in the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.mousebinding.gesture?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Comment: You bind commands but the gesture is specified in xaml like Gesture="Alt+MiddleClick"

Comment: Either define the gesture inline (in XAML) or in code-behind (in C#). Gestures are input related GUI events. They are not meant to be bound to a data model as such UI related behavior must always be defined with the view element that knows how to handle UI events. It's a design decision made by Microsoft. Frameworks usually enforce or encourage a certain design pattern. If gestures are customizable, then you must create a dedicated dependency property and bind the gestures to it. Then register them in the particular control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a DependencyProperty, but a normal CLR property. You can't bind him. See [public virtual InputGesture Gesture](https://source.dot.net/#PresentationCore/System/Windows/Input/Command/InputBinding.cs,135).

You can create a Behavior or an Attached Property for this purpose.

**Example:**

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Core2022.SO.Chris.AttachedProperties
{
    public static class InputBinding
    {
        /// <summary>Returns the value of the attached property Gesture for the <paramref name="inputBinding"/>.</summary>
        /// <param name="inputBinding"><see cref="System.Windows.Input.InputBinding"/>  whose property value will be returned.</param>
        /// <returns>Property value <see cref="InputGesture"/>.</returns>
        public static InputGesture GetGesture(System.Windows.Input.InputBinding inputBinding)
        {
            return (InputGesture)inputBinding.GetValue(GestureProperty);
        }

        /// <summary>Sets the value of the Gesture attached property to <paramref name="inputBinding"/>.</summary>
        /// <param name="inputBinding"><see cref="System.Windows.Input.InputBinding"/> whose property is setting to a value..</param>
        /// <param name="value"><see cref="InputGesture"/> value for property.</param>
        public static void SetGesture(System.Windows.Input.InputBinding inputBinding, InputGesture value)
        {
            inputBinding.SetValue(GestureProperty, value);
        }

        /// <summary><see cref="DependencyProperty"/> for methods <see cref="GetGesture(System.Windows.Input.InputBinding)"/>
        /// and <see cref="SetGesture(System.Windows.Input.InputBinding, InputGesture)"/>.</summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty GestureProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                nameof(GetGesture).Substring(3),
                typeof(InputGesture),
                typeof(InputBinding),
                new PropertyMetadata(null, OnGestureChanged));

        private static void OnGestureChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (d is not System.Windows.Input.InputBinding inputBinding)
                throw new NotImplementedException($"Implemented only for the \"{typeof(System.Windows.Input.InputBinding).FullName}\" class");

            inputBinding.Gesture = (InputGesture)e.NewValue;
        }
    }
}
```

```xml
<MouseBinding Command="helix:ViewportCommands.Rotate"
              ap:InputBinding.Gesture="{Binding ViewportRotateGesture}"/>
```

Comment: Tnx this worked for me! Also for anybody that is reading this and doesn’t know much about xaml: you also need to add the following to your xaml file: xmlns:ap="clr-namespace:YOURNAMESPACE"